# C# WPF - How to create submenu form BindingList without overwriting MenuItem style?

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

I'm trying to write just some sample application using MVVM. In my view, I have two MenuItems with submenus

```
<Menu >
<--!first submenu-->
    <MenuItem  Header="{Binding  AppViewModel.AppSubtitles[top_menu_navigation]}"  >
        <MenuItem Header="{Binding  AppViewModel.AppSubtitles[top_menu_go_forward]}" Command="{Binding NavigateForward}"  />
        <MenuItem  Header="{Binding  AppViewModel.AppSubtitles[top_menu_go_back]}" Command="{Binding NavigateBack}"   />
    </MenuItem>
<--!second submenu-->
    <MenuItem   ItemsSource="{Binding AppViewModel.AllLanguagesItems}" Header="{Binding  AppViewModel.AppSubtitles[top_menu_language]}" >
        <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style  TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" >
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ChangeLanguage}"/>
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

(items in AllLanguagesItems list have properties DisplayName and ChangeLanguage)

I also dynamically change application style by adding/removing ResourceDictionaries (with styles for buttons, menuitems etc.) to/from application MergedDictionaries.

The problem is that changing styles works well with first submenu, menuitems styles are updated correctly, but in second submenu, only partially - mainly, OnHover effect doesn't change.

Before adding dictionary
[First submenu before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knt3L.png)[Second submenu before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwzwA.png)

After adding dictionary
[First submenu after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlF3v.png)[Second submenu after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pObjf.png)

I assume it has something to do with overwriting styles, but how would you define bindings otherwise?
I tried

```
<MenuItem   ItemsSource="{Binding AppViewModel.AllLanguagesItems}" Header="{Binding  AppViewModel.AppSubtitles[top_menu_language]}" >
                <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding DisplayName}" MaxWidth="200" MaxHeight="20"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
            </MenuItem>
```

but it just creates MenuItem inside MenuItem
[MenuItem inside MenuItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqUtf.png)

EDIT:

Styles: https://github.com/Kaszub09/MVVM-WPF-DI-Sample/tree/master/WPFSampleApplication/ApplicationData/Themes

Comment: Child menu items ARE within parent menu items. That's how they work.  A menuitem is a headereditemscontrol. The header is what you're thinking of as a menuitem. The itemscontrol is the sub menu. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.headereditemscontrol?view=windowsdesktop-5.0

Comment: The header can be anything you like though. A usercontrol, another datatemplate or whatever.

Comment: You haven't defined a `Style` for second-level menu items then. Posting your current style(s) would be an idea.

Comment: @mm8 I added link to full styles, but I don't think that's the problem, if I were to create mulitlevel menu like below  styles are applied correctly. `<MenuItem><MenuItem/><MenuItem><MenuItem/><MenuItem/></MenuItem></MenuItem>`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [BasedOn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.style.basedon?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) property in your style

Comment: If I use `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}"`, it correctly creates style based on whatever style is present during MenuItem initialization (so I could get it to look like first one if I added this dictionary to Resources in App.xaml), but after that the style doesn't change when adding/removing dictionaries during runtime. (Styles in dictionaries are all along the lines of `<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">` meant to replace style of any control of given type)